# Menu enlarged when refresh the page in WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a problem when i refresh the page menu will enlarged for a second then back to normal size. Can any one share the reason

I think that was caused by some plugins but site is live now so i dont know what will do

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Plugins one by one and see what causes this issue.